# CUDA 5.5 not working in Ubuntu 12.04 with GTX 750 Ti

Tags: cuda, nvidia, cuda-gdb

I get the following error when trying to use a GTX 750 Ti with CUDA 5.5 in Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit:

> The driver installation is unable to locate the kernel source. Please make sure that the kernel source packages are installed and set up correctly. If you know that the kernel source packages are installed and set up correctly, you may pass the location of the kernel source ith the `--kernel-source-path` flag.

How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GeForce GTX 750 Ti is based on NVIDIA's new Maxwell architecture (compute capability 5.0) and requires CUDA 6.0.

Comment: Absolutely Right! I have installed the cuda-6.0 successfully! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The CUDA SDK is not related to your hardware if you got a problem of with a driver you might go on nvidia.com and find the right driver for your card. On their web site, there's an automatic setup. You just have to download what's noticed/

Comment: Thanks. The new graphical card is the `GTX 750ti`, and I download the cuda toolkit 5.5.

Comment: Nono look for the driver not for the CUDA SDK. You tried this: http://www.nvidia.fr/Download/index.aspx?lang=us ??